# flutter futureBuilder not working with bool return type

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the value from firestore and use it on my Switch widget.  The indicator that I am trying to read on this switch is bool (true or false only).  However it is not working, getting this error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of 'bool'

Here is my FetureBuilder code wrapped on my Switch:

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
                      future: getShipValue(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData == true) {
                          setState(() {
                            isSwitch = true;
                          });
                        }
                        return CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: isSwitch,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            handleSwitch(val);
                          },
                        );
                      }),
```

Here is my Function that I am referencing:

```
Future<bool> getShipValue() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('OrderDetails')
        .doc(order.orderId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      return value.data()!['ShippedInd'];
    });
  }
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.  Many thanks!
[image: schema here]

Comment: What line gives the error? Have you tried with 'return value.data()!['ShippedInd']==true' ?

Comment: Could you show an image of your database?

Comment: I think the data is returning null. So, to resolve this, We can say ```return (value.data()!['ShippedInd']==true)?true:false??false;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now. As many pointed, I needed to handle the bool(true/false) and such is my FutureBuilder code that worked.

```
Thank you all!

Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    isSwitch = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('OrderDetails')
        .doc(order.docid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      //return value.data()!['ShippedInd'] == true;
      //    print(value.data()!['ShippedInd']);
      return (value.data()!['ShippedInd'] == true) ? true : false;
    });
    return isSwitch;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     if(snapshot.data){
                         setState(() {
                                isSwitch = true;
                              });
                            }
    } else{
// Do sth else
}
```

Comment: I tried: return value.data()!['ShippedInd'] == true; but no luck... same error. Let me get a image of the db

Comment: @Lorenzo, I tried your solution but no luck, it's a boolian field and has value only true or false. also it will always have data no null, Thanks!

Comment: I added the schema above to my question.  Any other suggestions?